# Java Ibatis Iterate List

Tags: ibatis, loops

Java i am using ibatis

using in clause want to iterate inside in clause, every one talking about following solution but when i try it gives me following error.

```
**Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named '[]' in class 'java.util.List'**


List entityIds = new ArrayList(2);
       entityIds.add(42167777);
       entityIds.add(43178455);

(List<EventCategory>)sqlMapClient.queryForList("getEventCategoryByEntityIds", entityIds);

<select id="getEventCategoryByEntityIds" parameterClass="java.util.List" resultMap="eventCategoryDetails">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT E.EVENTCATEGORYID, ECAT.Name EVENTCATEGORYNAME, E.EVENTSUBCATEGORYID , ESUBCAT.Name EVENTSUBCATEGORYNAME  FROM
        Event E (nolock)
        JOIN EVENTCATEGORY ECAT (nolock) ON E.EventCategoryId=ECAT.EventCategoryId JOIN EVENTCATEGORY ESUBCAT ON E.EVENTSUBCATEGORYID=ESUBCAT.EventCategoryId 
        <dynamic prepend="where ENTITYID in ">
          <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
          #[]#
          </iterate>
        </dynamic>
        ]]>
  </select>
```

I am sick and tried trying this solution but not working. any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading same kind of problem over the forum, I only removed the `<![CDATA[` and it started working.

Does anybody know why this happens? Please share with the rest of us.

Comment: I believe the CDATA tags would prevent ibatis from doing dynamic sql?

Answer (score 1):

if you watch the ibatis doc you will find the explanation of CDATA in chapter 3.2.3.1. Escaping XML symbols.

Because you are combining SQL and XML in a single document, conflicts can occur. The most common conflict is the greater-than and less-than symbols (><). SQL statements use these symbols as operators, but they are reserved symbols in XML. A simple solution is to "escape" the SQL statements that uses XML reserved symbols within a CDATA element.

```
<statement
    id="selectPersonsByAge" parameterClass=”int” resultClass="person">
    <![CDATA[ SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE AGE > #value# ]]>
</statement>
```